# Referencing Other Tables for an SQL Select statement

Tags: sql

I have two tables and they are connected via the 'debt_key' here are the table structures

**Note** table:

```
Note_Key (numeric(9,0),not null)
Debtor_Key(numeric(9,0),not null)
Debt_Key(numeric(9,0),not null)
User_Key(numeric(5,0),not null)
Note_Date(datetime, not null)
Note_Time(char(8),not null)
Note_Text(Char(80),not null)
```

**Debt** table:

```
Debt_key
ACCT
```

....and so on, but we only need to use those two fields.

So I am trying to add new notes with a date and time into the Note table. So far I have been unsuccessful. Here is the basic outcome of what I have written:

```
INSERT INTO NOTE (b.NOTE_DATE, b.NOTE_TIME, b.NOTE_TEXT)
VALUES('2012-07-11 00:00:00.000','00:00:00','ASSIGNED FOR PI CONTACT')
   SELECT NOTE_DATE, NOTE_TIME, NOTE_TEXT 
   FROM DEBT a JOIN NOTE B ON B.DEBT_KEY = A.DEBT_KEY AND A.DEBT_KEY = '5797071'
```

When I execute it is giving me this error:

> Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'NOTE_KEY', table
>   'Ads_Mast.dbo.NOTE'; column does not allow nulls. INSERT fails. The
>   statement has been terminated.

I cannot add a value to the Note_key column though as it is auto incremented. Any ideas?

Thanks.

Comment: You have seven columns - all `NOT NULL` - in your `Note` table. If you want to insert a row, you need to insert values **for all seven columns** (or have default constraints on them). Your first `INSERT` only attempts to insert three columns .....

Comment: Those are the only three columns that I am able to edit though, that is why I wrote it to only insert into the three. 3 of the foriegn keys I can not do anything about and the Note_Key is auto increment.

Comment: Since I cannot edit those, how can I write it to allow them to update themselves?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are trying to `INSERT` new notes, then need to use an `INSERT INTO SELECT FROM` if you are joining with a second table.  You will also need to include values for each field in your Notes table:

```
INSERT INTO NOTE 
(
    Note_Key,
    Debtor_Key,
    Debt_Key,
    User_Key,
    NOTE_DATE, 
    NOTE_TIME, 
    NOTE_TEXT
)
SELECT b.Note_Key, a.Debtor_Key, a.Debt_Key, b.NOTE_DATE, a.User_Key, b.NOTE_TIME, b.NOTE_TEXT 
FROM DEBT a JOIN NOTE B 
    ON B.DEBT_KEY = A.DEBT_KEY 
WHERE A.DEBT_KEY = '5797071'
```

If you know all of the values you want to submit then you would need to do the following:

```
INSERT INTO NOTE 
(
    Debtor_Key,
    Debt_Key,
    User_Key,
    NOTE_DATE, 
    NOTE_TIME, 
    NOTE_TEXT
)
VALUES
(
    0, -- the Debtor_Key value
    1, -- the Debt_Key value
    1, -- the User_Key value
    '2012-07-11 00:00:00.000',
    '00:00:00',
    'ASSIGNED FOR PI CONTACT'
)
```

Edit: If you have some constant values and some values from a table then do the following:

```
INSERT INTO NOTE 
(
    Debtor_Key,
    Debt_Key,
    User_Key,
    NOTE_DATE, 
    NOTE_TIME, 
    NOTE_TEXT
)
SELECT a.Debtor_Key
    , a.Debt_Key
    , '2012-07-11 00:00:00.000'
    , a.User_Key
    , '00:00:00'
    , 'ASSIGNED FOR PI CONTACT'
FROM DEBT a JOIN NOTE B 
    ON B.DEBT_KEY = A.DEBT_KEY 
WHERE A.DEBT_KEY = '5797071'
```

But if you just want to `UPDATE` specific values, then you can use an `UPDATE`:

```
UPDATE b
SET NOTE_DATE = '2012-07-11 00:00:00.000'
    , NOTE_TIME = '00:00:00'
    , NOTE_TEXT = 'ASSIGNED FOR PI CONTACT'
FROM Note b
JOIN DEBT a
    ON B.DEBT_KEY = A.DEBT_KEY
WHERE  A.DEBT_KEY = '5797071'
```

Comment: And I hope that `Debtor_Key`, `Debt_Key` and `User_Key` all have default values, since they're `NOT NULL` but you're not inserting any values for them.

Comment: There are already "Notes" in the note field, I can not just update it. The Debtor_key, debt_key, and User_key are all already in other tables (Debtor table, Debt table, and User table).

Comment: I dont understand how your first piece of syntax works. Where does the 'note_text' go that I need to put into that field?

Comment: @Mark do you want to append the notes to the already existing ones? Or do you need to join on all of the tables to get the fields?

Comment: @Mark the first one is selecting the values from the tables in the select statement.

Comment: @ bluefeet - I would be basically adding a new ROW with a date, time, and note text (note_date, note_time, note_text). So I would not be adding to a particular field that is already on the table. Just a new record in that table.

Comment: @bluefeet, I understand it is selecting the values, but how do I actually put in the note_text. The actual string of words 'Insert note text here.'

Comment: @bluefeet, thanks for the edit. But how do I use the specific debt_key to insert the information in?

Comment: @Mark you would use a combination of the first and the second INSERT to get your final result.  In the fields you know the values, use the static value, in the others you would return the value from your table

Comment: @bluefeet - Currently this statment did not work.INSERT INTO NOTE ( NOTE_KEY, Debtor_Key, Debt_Key, User_Key, NOTE_DATE, NOTE_TIME, NOTE_TEXT ) VALUES ( 0, 0, -- the Debtor_Key value 1, -- the Debt_Key value 0, -- the User_Key value '2012-07-11 00:00:00.000', '00:00:00', 'ASSIGNED FOR PI CONTACT' ) SELECT b.Note_Key, a.Debtor_Key, a.Debt_Key, b.NOTE_DATE, b.User_Key, b.NOTE_TIME, b.NOTE_TEXT FROM DEBT a JOIN NOTE B ON B.DEBT_KEY = A.DEBT_KEY WHERE A.DEBT_KEY = '5797071'

Comment: @bluefeet - This is throwing an error saying: Error converting data type varchar to numeric. I am not sure what to use for the time field in this case. I thought it would be '00:00:00' as it is a char (8)

Comment: @bluefeet - Or is this actually not the correct location of the error? It doesnt say a line number unfortunatly.

Comment: @Mark please create a [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com) with the tables and some sample data

Comment: @bluefeet, I am not able to create the tables. It is not allowing me to create certain datatypes in there (datetime) Any other ideas?

Comment: I was thinking that there may be an issue with the unique identier that I am using? Maybe it doesnt like the format? I dont know